# Prolog - re-load consult('filename') to interpreter

Tags: prolog, swi-prolog

After I load a **pl** file to **SWI-Prolog** with `consult('filename')`  how could I re-load it by using keyboard ? I read that it possible with `ctr b` but it doesn't work  .

I use SWI-Prolog version 6.2.6 .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Call the predefined `make/0` predicate. It will reload all of your changed source files.

```
?- make.
```

More information here: http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=make/0

Answer (score 1):

the consult/1 in SWI-prolog is actually defined as reconsult/1

but make is niftier.